# OnMessageRecieved not getting fired in background app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get redirect to a diffrent paged on clicking diffrent notifications.
The OnMessagedRecieved isn't getting triggered when the app is running in the background only when its on the foreground.

According to the documentation [notification foreground, background](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive) its the System tray that gets triggered.

So i looked up how to get it working on the background, I found this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@shayan.ta69/how-to-handle-fcm-notification-in-backgrounded-android-applications-29229c4f9975).

Accordign to this tutorial:

> As explained below, by using FCM console you can only send notification messages. notification messages can be handled by the onMessageReceived method in foregrounded application and deliver to the device’s system tray in backgrounded application. User taps on notification and default application launcher will be opened. if you want to handle notification in every state of application you must use data message and onMessageReceived method.

So i looked up what exactly a data message is and what a notification message is. [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

I folowed the tutorial but its not working for me.
This is my code :

```
public async Task<bool> WakeUp(string[] tokens)
    {
        var message = new Message()
        {
            RegistrationID= tokens,
            Notification = new Notification()
            {
                Title = "testing",
                Body = "test"
            },
            Android = new AndroidConfig()
            {
                Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                {
                    Color = "#FF0000",
                    ClickAction = "MyActivity"
                }
            },
            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {
                    "notificationType", NotificationType.WakeUp.ToString()
                }
            }
        };

        return await SendAsyncMessage(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


public async Task<bool> SendAsyncMessage(Message message)
    {
        var jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod, FIREBASE_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_URL)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(jsonMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"key={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirebaseNotificationServerKey"]}");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sender", $"id={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirebaseNotificationSenderID"]}");
        HttpResponseMessage result;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            result = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
```

This is how i recieve my code in my app

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("message recieved");
    }
```

Raw Json

```
{
"registration_ids":["myToken"],
"condition":null,
"data":
{
    "notificationType":"WakeUp"
},
"notification":
{
    "title":"testing",
    "body":"test",
    "image":null
},
"android":
{
    "collapse_key":null,
    "restricted_package_name":null,
    "data":null,
    "notification":
    {
        "title":null,
        "body":null,
        "icon":null,
        "color":"#FF0000",
        "sound":null,
        "tag":null,
        "image":null,
        "click_action":"mActivity",
        "title_loc_key":null,
        "title_loc_args":null,
        "body_loc_key":null,
        "body_loc_args":null,
        "channel_id":null
    },
    "fcm_options":null,
    "priority":"high",
    "ttl":null
},
"webpush":null,
"apns":null,
"fcm_options":null,
"topic":null
```

}

The notification is recieved but the OnMessageRecieved isn't triggered. I think the notification center is the one responsible for the notification being shown.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What does the raw json message look like

Comment: @tyczj i edited the page. Forgot about that sorry

Comment: As you can see `"data":null,` is null no its never going to get sent to the background

Comment: @tyczj That data is empty but the one above that isn't. The title and the body are also in the general Notifications as the Data i filled in so i would assume android can read it from there aswell. I could be misstaken

Comment: @tyczj I changed my code to also putt data in the empty data property. It still however doesn't trigger

Comment: I would look over the documentation again. I cannot put my finger on exactly what but what you have does not look like the example in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Why is this happening?

There are two types of messages in FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging):

1. **Display Messages**: These messages trigger the `onMessageReceived()` callback only when your app is in **foreground**
2. **Data Messages**: Theses messages trigger the `onMessageReceived()` callback **even** if your app is in **foreground/background/killed**

> **NOTE:** Firebase team have not developed a UI to send `data-messages` to
>   your devices, yet. You should use your server for sending this type!

### 2. How to?

To achieve this, you have to perform a `POST` request to the following URL:

> `POST` https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

#### Headers

- **Key:** `Content-Type`, **Value:** `application/json`
- **Key:** `Authorization`, **Value:** `key=<your-server-key>`

#### Body using topics

```
{
    "to": "/topics/my_topic",
    "data": {
        "my_custom_key": "my_custom_value",
        "my_custom_key2": true
     }
}
```

#### Or if you want to send it to specific devices

```
{
    "data": {
        "my_custom_key": "my_custom_value",
        "my_custom_key2": true
     },
    "registration_ids": ["{device-token}","{device2-token}","{device3-token}"]
}
```

> **NOTE:** Be sure you're **not adding** JSON key `notification`
>   
> **NOTE:** To get your server key, you can find it in the firebase console: `Your project -> settings -> Project settings -> Cloud messaging -> Server Key`

### 3. How to handle the push notification message?

This is how you handle the received message:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { 
     Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
     String myCustomKey = data.get("my_custom_key");

     // Manage data
}
```

this is refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/10768653)